# Loop (or lapply) a slice function for a datafile and saving each new part as different csvs in R

Tags: r, loops, slice, export-to-csv, lapply

I have a csv. It includes recorded values for each half hour per day.
I want to `slice` it in half hour blocks (separated by a "system sleep." text), and save each separated blocks as an independent .csv files for further analysis.
My current code;

`df <- read.csv("datafile",h=T,sep=",")`

`M <- which(startsWith(df$ID, "system sleep."))`

`M2 <- M[1]`

`df2 <- slice(df,c(1:M2-1))`

`write.csv(write_csv(df2, file = paste0("test", df2$Time[1], "-", ".csv")))`

I do the `M2 <- M[1]` so I can target the first system sleep. I have tried using `M2 <- M[i]` instead, but it is not working so far. I can slice and save the first part but I want to loop it so it keeps going for the rest. Maybe I can have a different approach but this is the best I found so far for me.

An modified and simplified example about how the file looks like is:

| ID | Day | Time | Rec | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 00:00 | 1 | 251 |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 00:01 | 2 | 368 |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 00:02 | 3 | 430 |
| system sleep. |  |  |  |  |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 00:30 | 1 | 195 |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 00:31 | 2 | 876 |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 00:32 | 3 | 864 |
| system sleep. |  |  |  |  |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 01:00 | 1 | 872 |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 01:01 | 2 | 120 |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 01:02 | 3 | 208 |
| system sleep. |  |  |  |  |
| (...) | (...) | (...) | (...) | (...) |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 23:39 | 10 | 002 |

**Thank you**

Comment: please upload your simplified data as a `dput()`-sample so it can be copied into an r session

Answer (score 0):

Instead of slicing you could add a block identifier column to your dataset. Afterwards you could split the data into blocks and use e.g. `lapply` to export your data into separate csvs:

Note: Wasn't sure whether you want to keep the "system sleep" row. In my code below I decided to drop it.

```r
# Add block identifier
dat$block <- cumsum(grepl("^sys", dat$ID))
# Get rid of "sys sleep"
dat <- dat[!grepl("^sys", dat$ID),]
# Split into blocks
dat_split <- split(dat, dat$block)
# Export
path <- tempdir()

foo <- lapply(dat_split, function(x) write.csv(x, file = file.path(path, paste0("test", x$Time[[1]], "-", ".csv")), row.names = FALSE))

# Check
fns <- list.files(path = path, pattern = "\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)
lapply(fns, read.csv)
#> [[1]]
#>   ID       Day  Time Rec value block
#> 1 A1 2018/1/30 00:00   1   251     0
#> 2 A1 2018/1/30 00:01   2   368     0
#> 3 A1 2018/1/30 00:02   3   430     0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   ID       Day  Time Rec value block
#> 1 A1 2018/1/30 00:30   1   195     1
#> 2 A1 2018/1/30 00:31   2   876     1
#> 3 A1 2018/1/30 00:32   3   864     1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   ID       Day  Time Rec value block
#> 1 A1 2018/1/30 01:00   1   872     2
#> 2 A1 2018/1/30 01:01   2   120     2
#> 3 A1 2018/1/30 01:02   3   208     2
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>   ID       Day  Time Rec value block
#> 1 A1 2018/1/30 23:39  10     2     3
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
  ID = c(
    "A1", "A1", "A1",
    "system sleep.", "A1", "A1", "A1",
    "system sleep.", "A1", "A1", "A1", "system sleep.",
    "A1"
  ),
  Day = c(
    "2018/1/30",
    "2018/1/30", "2018/1/30", NA, "2018/1/30", "2018/1/30",
    "2018/1/30", NA, "2018/1/30", "2018/1/30",
    "2018/1/30", NA, "2018/1/30"
  ),
  Time = c(
    "00:00", "00:01",
    "00:02", NA, "00:30", "00:31", "00:32", NA,
    "01:00", "01:01", "01:02", NA, "23:39"
  ),
  Rec = c(
    "1", "2", "3", NA,
    "1", "2", "3", NA, "1", "2", "3", NA,
    "10"
  ),
  value = c(
    "251", "368",
    "430", NA, "195", "876", "864", NA, "872", "120",
    "208", NA, "002"
  )
)
```